# $ symbol causes program to crash

Tags: c++

Here is my program:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string hash = crypt("asd123","$2a$13$IP4FT4gf123I5bT6o4123123123123nbEXFqo.Oa123");
    std::cout << hash;
}
```

Running this causes the error

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
>    what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
>   Aborted (core dumped)

but if I remove the $ from the salt it runs fine.

Comment: Have you tried reading some [documentation of `crypt`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/crypt.html)?

Comment: First, catch the exception. Then - in the doc of crypt, you'll find why it throws.

Answer (score 4):

The error message tells you that `crypt` returns a nullpointer for the given arguments. Most likely that's its way to signal failure. You need to check for that.

You can find out more about `crypt` by (1) finding documentation of the function, and (2) reading it.

For example, you can google “unistd crypt”.

And it so happens that the documentation specifies the valid set of characters you can use, in a nice table.